# How to set a value on a specific page template in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

New to Gatsby and can't get past this issue. I created a new page and on that page I want to change a value that is used in template file for the logo. On page 'my-mobile-app.js' I need to use the 'pulse' logo. Ive added it to the export default below but how do I call it from the specific page? Adding  `dark={true}` to the `<Img>` changes it globally as expected. Let me know if this isn't clear.

This is the page structure:

- my-mobiel-app.js (new page that needs to have a different logo than all others)

  - import Layout from '../../components/layout'
- src/components/layout.js

  - import Header from "./Header"
- src/components/Header/Header.js

  - import Logo from '../Logo'
- And finally src/components/Logo.js has this code:

  ```
    export default ({ white, dark, pulse, ...props }) => {
        const logo = useStaticQuery(graphql`
            query {
                white: file(relativePath: { eq: "logo/Logo-whitebg.png" }) {
                    childImageSharp {
                        fluid {
                            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_noBase64
                        }
                    }
                }
                dark: file(relativePath: { eq: "logo/Logo-darkbg.png" }) {
                    childImageSharp {
                        fluid {
                            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_noBase64
                        }
                    }
                }
                pulse: file(relativePath: { eq: "logo/Logo-pulse.svg" }) {
                    childImageSharp {
                        fluid {
                            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_noBase64
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        `)
    }
    const typeLogo = (white && 'white') || (dark && 'dark') || (pulse && 'pulse') || "white"
    return <Link to="/">
        <Img
            fluid={logo[typeLogo].childImageSharp.fluid}
            alt="Tradovate Logo"
            {...props}
            loading="eager"
            fadeIn={false}
        />
    </Link>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's preferrable to export a named component (can be default) like:

```
 export default function Logo ({ white, dark, pulse, ...props }) => {
      const logo = useStaticQuery(graphql`
          query {
              white: file(relativePath: { eq: "logo/Logo-whitebg.png" }) {
                  childImageSharp {
                      fluid {
                          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_noBase64
                      }
                  }
              }
              dark: file(relativePath: { eq: "logo/Logo-darkbg.png" }) {
                  childImageSharp {
                      fluid {
                          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_noBase64
                      }
                  }
              }
              pulse: file(relativePath: { eq: "logo/Logo-pulse.svg" }) {
                  childImageSharp {
                      fluid {
                          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_noBase64
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      `)
  }
  const typeLogo = (white && 'white') || (dark && 'dark') || (pulse && 'pulse') || "white"
  return <Link to="/">
      <Img
          fluid={logo[typeLogo].childImageSharp.fluid}
          alt="Tradovate Logo"
          {...props}
          loading="eager"
          fadeIn={false}
      />
  </Link>
```

Then wherever you want you just need to:

```
import Logo from '../path/to/your/brand/new/component'

<Logo white />
```

Change `white` or `dark` accordingly. I think it would be more clear if you create a boolean like `isWhite` or `isDark` and set it as default as `true` or `false`, whatever works for you like:

```
export default function Logo ({ isWhite=false, pulse, ...props }) => {}
```

In that way, you don't need to pass always a `<Logo isWhite={false} />` because it's set as a default value to false. If you pass it like `<Logo isWhite={true} />` will override the default configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, still can't get this to work. I want to go the boolean route, as this is an existing app and Im just needing to change the logo on one page and don't want it to affect all existing content. When add the "isWhite=true, isDark=false, ispulse=false...props" then set it to true, getting a syntax error and crashes local server

Comment: Without seeing the crash it's difficult to guess the issue. You just need to use a default value on the needed destructuring properties

Comment: IM going to try and silo off these files and make a set just for my page and see if I can get it to work. The re-attempt the boolean version - which is how I want to end. Tough learning curve here.

Comment: The silo - ugly coding version worked. To accomplish using the boolean, and leaving the existing pages working as expected - how do you set a default value (to keep everything working as is) and then on one page send a value to override it?

Comment: Can you share your current snippet version?

Comment: https://codepen.io/DirtyBirdDesign/pen/gOXdWYP
this is the less than optimal solution. Everything I try with the preferred, boolean method crashes.

Comment: Better solution, but not working -> https://codepen.io/DirtyBirdDesign/pen/vYWzmYY

Comment: Ok... If you change the props naming to `isWhite` or `isDark`, your variables names in `typeLogo` must change accordingly, otherwise can cause a compilation break (syntax error) because they aren't defined. In addition, add the `function` keyword in your component exportation. Should be `export default function Logo({})`

Comment: Using export default function Logo ({ isWhite={true}, isDark={false}, isPulse={false}, ...props }) => { ()} returns this error :sourceMessage: "/Users/Zen/WebSites/SiteName/www/src/components/Logo-Pulse.js: Unexpected keyword 'true'. (5:45)\n" +

Comment: Don't change the code, please. You just need to copy and paste `export default function Logo ({ isWhite=false, pulse, ...props }) => {}`. Spot the `isWhite=true`, not `isWhite={true}`

Comment: Got that sorted - and works as expected. This way is much more efficient now.